Matrix representation of coupled harmonic oscillator differential equations
So I have this exercise, where I have to write the second order differential equations of coupled harmonic oscilators into first order equations, and put it in matrix form. So from
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcrcr}
x_1'' & = & -(k_1 + k_2)\,x_1 & + & k_2\,x_2
\\[1mm]
x_2'' & = & k_2\,x_1 & - & (k_1 + k_2)\,x_2
\end{array}\right.
$$
into
$
\begin{aligned}
    x_1' &= y_1, \\
    y_1' &= -(k_1 + k_2)x_1 + k_2x_2, \\
    x_2' &= y_2, \\
    y_2' &= k_2x_1 - (k_1 + k_2)x_2.
\end{aligned}
$
I've seen from another post that you can get the matrix representation (to get the equation form $X' = AX$) as follows:
$A =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-(k_1 + k_2) & 0 & k_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
k_2 & 0 & -(k_1 + k_2) & 0
\end{pmatrix}$
When calculating the eigenvalues of this matrix, you get a complicated characteristic equation where some of the eigenvalues are complex. What I want to ask is, can you change the matrix representation such that you get the system:
$\begin{pmatrix}
y_1' \\
y_2' \\
x_1' \\
x_2'
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-(k_1 + k_2) & k_2 & 0 & 0 \\
k_2 & -(k_1 + k_2) & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
y_1 \\
y_2
\end{pmatrix}?$
Doing $AX$ gives $X'$, so it should be fine (?). This matrix yields much simpler eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and a simple general solution. However, I have not seen any approaches use this method, which makes me believe that its incorrect. Any feedback is appreciated!

How do you find the general solution from the eigenvalues in this rewrite? The right hand side is not AX if the left hand side is X'.

@Paul I'm new to this topic; could you be more explicit please?

The order of the variables in $X’$ and $X$ has to remain the same. This is not the case in your second equation

@whpowell96 ahhh, okay. I guess it makes sense. What a stupid mistake. Thank you...

Write $x’’{n} = -\omega^{2}x{n}$ with $n \in \left{1, 2\right}$.  You’ll get an eigenvalue equation  for $\omega$ or/and $\omega^{2}$.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iverson}[1]{\left[\left[\,{#1}\,\right]\right]}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
With
$\ds{k_{1},\ k_{2}\ \in\
\mathbb{R}_{\,>\, 0}}$:
$$
\color{#44f}{\left\{\begin{array}{rcrcr}
x_{1}'' & = & -\pars{k_{1} + k_{2}}x_{1} & + & k_{2}\,x_{2}
\\[1mm]
x_{2}'' & = & k_{2}\,x_{1} & - & \pars{k_{1} + k_{2}}x_{2}
\end{array}\right.}
$$
$\large '$ means "derivative respect of time $\ds{\large t}$".

Lets $\ds{x_{k}'' = -\omega^{2}x_{k}}$. Then, 
\begin{align}
& \left\{\begin{array}{rcrcr}
0 & = & \bracks{\omega^{2} - \pars{k_{1} + k_{2}}}x_{1} & + & k_{2}\,x_{2}
\\[1mm]
0 & = & k_{2}\,x_{1} & + &
\bracks{\omega^{2} - \pars{k_{1} + k_{2}}}x_{2}
\end{array}\right.
\\[5mm] & \implies
\bracks{\omega^{2} - \pars{k_{1} + k_{2}}}^{2} - k_{2}^{2} = 0
\\[2mm] & \implies
\omega^{2} = k_{1} + k_{2} \pm k_{2}
\\[2mm] & \implies
\pars{\omega_{+} \atop \omega_{-}} = 
\pars{\root{k_{1} + 2k_{2}}  \atop
\root{k_{1}}}
\end{align}
with solutions
\begin{align}
&  \left\{\begin{array}{rcccl}
\ds{x_{1+}\pars{t}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-x_{2+}\pars{t}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\sin\pars{\omega_{+}t + \delta_{+}}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{x_{1-}\pars{t}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{x_{2-}\pars{t}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\sin\pars{\omega_{-}t + \delta_{-}}}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
The general solution becomes
$$
\bbx{\color{#44f}{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{x_{1}\pars{t}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{A\sin\pars{\omega_{-}t + \delta_{-}} +
B\sin\pars{\omega_{+}t + \delta_{+}}}
\\
\ds{x_{2}\pars{t}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{
A\sin\pars{\omega_{-}t + \delta_{-}} -
B\sin\pars{\omega_{+}t + \delta_{+}}} 
\end{array}}}
$$
